# Would shooting the tyres prevent a takeoff?

Tags: takeoff, landing-gear

In the movie *[Fast & Furious 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_%26_Furious_6),* among other questionable parts of one scene, they try to prevent a very large aircraft from takeoff.

As opposed to whatever they tried, how effective would it be in preventing takeoff to shoot the tyres?

Comment: Would shooting the tyres actually have much effect? Aircraft tyres are somewhat stronger than car tyres and somewhat less strong than, say, mining truck tyres. Shooting car tyres seems to work; shooting mining truck tyres would clearly do nothing.

Comment: Prevent a takeoff, no.  Prevent a successful _rejection_ of a takeoff, on the other hand, yes.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
(FAA takeoff safety)

If a tire failed/burst during takeoff at high speed, it is recommended to continue the takeoff.

[image]

The [*Face/Off*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face/Off) method may work however, quickly grab a helicopter, shoot one of the engines, when that fails, land the helicopter on the tail. In Hollywood, haste is not required as they have endless runways.

Comment: Would shooting the tyres be likely to cause them to fail? They're a good deal stronger than car tyres.

Comment: Assuming they could. Whether any particular gun could pierce a couple centimetres of rubber and air pressurised at 200psi is probably a question for the guys over at engineering.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Googling that would not be recommended :'D